# setting up environment in virtaulenv using python3 stuck on setuptools, pip, wheel

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.4

Running the following:

`virtualenv -p python3 venv`

gives:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/taivanbatb/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /specific/a/home/cc/students/csguests/taivanbatb/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
```

which is where it gets stuck.

Calling CTRL-C gives:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 671, in main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(popen.wait())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1376, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 769, in call_subprocess
    line = stdout.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599428/virtualenv-hung-up-on-installing-setuptools).

As suggested in the linked question, I tried installing with `--no-wheel` but to no avail. And I am sure it is not a network connectivity problem because setting up an environment using python2 using `virtualenv env` gives no errors.

The specific versions of all the packages I am using are as follows:

python 3.4.0
python 2.7.6
virtualenv 15.1.0

Comment: I've seen that before as well. [This workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623195/2296458) seems to work, but I still have no explanation for why the hang happens in the first place.

Comment: @CoryKramer the workaround you linked doesn't work if I'm using python3 like `virtualenv -p python3 venv --no-wheel`... it still gets stuck

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: @kshikama this is the output of uname -a `Linux rack-wolfson-g02 4.9.5-64-net1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 25 21:01:00 IST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with Python 3.4 and virtualenv 15.1.0

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you might need to use `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` first before running python3...

Comment: Could you try to create the virtual environment with `python3 -m venv venv`? Note that `venv` appears twice. The first one is the module name, the second one is the name of your virtual environment. Using `venv` is the preferred way to create virtual environments since Python3.3.

Comment: I agree with @ian0411. Try uninstalling your virtualenv module and installing again with sudo pip3. Notice that when you break the script it is running virtualenv from python2.7 directories. Worth trying. Another thing is your python 3 installation. Try giving the full path for your -p option on virtualenv, so you are sure you will have the right executable.

Comment: You should use the -v (verbose output) to get more info where it is stucking.

Comment: @Vineet Jain, see the attached picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcnmA.jpg) that I tried on my machine (with both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed).  `pip` is a link to `pip3` if there is no other versions of Python installed.  But still check where your `pip` and `pip3` real paths are just to be safe.

Comment: Please try running with verbose flag: `virtualenv -v -p python3 venv` and update the question with output. The next step is to try with `strace` to see where it stucks: `strace -vf virtualenv -v -p python3 venv`.

Answer (score 15):

1.Check your internet connections.

2.Set python3 as your default python interpreter since you have python2.7 as your default python interpreter. Try using without any wheel by:

```
virtualenv venv --no-wheel
```

Then activate virtualenv and run:-

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
pip install wheel --no-cache
```

If you are behind proxy then use:-
`sudo pip download setuptools pip wheel --proxy http://<yourproxyhere>`

After all this `virtualenv -p python3 venv` is working in my virtualenv ***perfectly***.
***NOTE***: Assuming virtual environment is already set in your system and python3 is your default interpreter.

> Alternatively, you don't need to do `virtualenv -p python3 venv`. You can specify python interpreter(present in /usr/bin/* folder) which you want to use in virtualenv and use it like this:-
>       **virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/pythonX.Y 
>     /home/username/path/to/virtualenv_name**
>
> if you want to install in the current working directory then you can use:-
>       **virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/pythonX.Y  virtualenv_name**
>   [REFERENCE](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RebuildingVirtualenvs/)

Comment: The internet connection was the problem for me. I was behind a proxy on my company's network. I used my home internet, and it all went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace indicates you are using virtualenv from your 2.7 installation. This would indicate that your PATH is not set for 3.x.  Start a new shell, set the PATH so that /usr/local/lib/python2.7 is not on it, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv` is a just a python package. And you can install it both on python2 and python3.

In my experience, virtualenv on python3 handles both python versions well. Your stacktrace shows that you use virtualenv for python2 - try switching to python3.

To install it on python3, run

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

or, if you have to use apt-get for some reason,

```
apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

try this when net connect is not available:

```
virtualenv --no-setuptools --no-wheel env_only_pip
```

you can still use pip when enter virtualenv

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=file:py_package -r requirements.txt
```