# How do I change PIP to use Python 2.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, python-2.x

I am on AWS Ec2 Amazon AMI. Trying to install virtualenv but PIP is set to use Python2.6

```
# pip -V && virtualenv --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory

# python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

I tried uninstalling virtualenv and reinstalling it but no luck.

```
#pip install virtualenv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Here is the install directory:

```
# which pip
/usr/sbin/pip
# which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Does it really make a difference. You can specify `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>`. If you need to use 2.7 version then you can specify like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`python2.7 -m pip install virtualenv`
  [Reference  Python official document](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel)

2.You can Install virtualenv for any python interpreter and use for a different python interpreter like:-

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

and then if you want to use python2.7 python interpreter then run following command to make virtualenv:-

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 virtualenv_name
```

**NOTE** :- python2.7 interpreter has to be present in `/usr/bin/*` folder
 For more on above command see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903517/6761181) answer

Comment: so I guess i need to python2.7 -m pip each time when I want to install things to 2.7?

Comment: @Maca If you want to change your default python interpreter to python2.7 then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256389/6761181).