# Multiple Version Python and Virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have 2 versions of Python installed in my machine (Windows 10 x64):
Python 2.7 x64
Python 3.6 x64
Python 3.6 x86

I created a virtualenv for each one of these versions. But when i activate the Python 3.6 x64 envirtonment and type in

`python --version`

it outputs Python 2.7.14

The other virtualenvs work correctly

Any one have an idea why Python 3.6.3 x64 env doesn't activate correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you make your python3 virtual env?  I would try `python3 -m venv myvirtualenv` to make sure you are creating it with a python3 interpreter

Comment: Nope, I have the same multiple python version setup (using anaconda) at work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up environment in virtaulenv using python3 stuck on setuptools, pip, wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674311/setting-up-environment-in-virtaulenv-using-python3-stuck-on-setuptools-pip-whe)

Comment: @SciGuy. First i install virtualenv in Pyhon 3.6 and put this commands in prompt:
1 - cd C:\Python36
2 - Scripts\virtualenv D:\VirtualEnvs\p36env